# Cant show result in array

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in the programming world and trying to do this little app for the first time working with WPF but I can't "print" my results from an array in the label.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
    DispatcherTimer tick = new DispatcherTimer();


    public int I = 0;
    public string[] temporaryResult = new string[5];
    public bool start = false;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        updates();
    }

    private void updates()
    {
        tick.Start();
        tick.Tick += Tick;
    }

    private void Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Display.Content = Math.Round(clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, 0);
        test.Content = temporaryResult[I];
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!start)
        {
            clock.Reset();
            clock.Start();
            start = true;
        }
        else
        {
            clock.Stop();
            start = false;
            temporaryResult[I] = clock.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
            I++;
            Debug.Print(temporaryResult[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

In method tick, I try to show my result with

`test.Content = temporaryResult[I];`

It doesn't work. But when I use

`test.Content = temporaryResult[0];`

It works at least once.

Comment: You are incrementing `I` (`I++`) **after** you insert a value at `temporaryResult[I]` so `I` points to an empty index. You probably want to increment first (although the code is a little strange, but I guess it's for learning)

Comment: Bro thanks! I am an idiot :) thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping Xerillio!

> You are incrementing I (I++) after you insert a value at temporaryResult[I] so I points to an empty index.